# Text as HTML in Mustache.js

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have an array like this in JavaScript:

```
[name: "myname", text: "<p>my html text</p>"]
```

Now when I use this in my Mustache template it displays the text as:

```
<p>my html text</p>
```

I just want to have it as html, like:

```
my html text
```

--

The template I use is something like this:

```
<div>
    {{name}}
    {{html}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

use triple curly braces if you want to output html. `{{{html}}}`

from the docs:

> All variables are HTML-escaped by default. If you want to render unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}. You can also use & to unescape a variable.

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Comment: triple curly braces, now you've gone mad!!

Answer (score 0):

{{{}}}
triple bracket syntax will not work if you using mustache for text message.
instead of this you can use below mention regex
`replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '')`