# using mustache.js to make table

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache

I'm getting data from database, putting them in a HTML table. and then sending it to the html file :

```
listAllResults(function (VariableWithNoName){
    console.log ( 'getting the data ' ) ;
    res.render('addPlaces', {title: 'addPlaces', places_list: VariableWithNoName}); 
});
```

VariableWithNoName is the table the table is generated in this way :

```
show = show + '<tr><td>' + result['BasicInfo[Name]'] + '</td></tr>';
```

The it is sent by the callback. But in the page it shows the result, but is shows the html code like :

```
<table><tr><td>Some name</td></tr><tr><td>Øyvinds Cuban Casa</td></tr></table>
```

rather than a table with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot be certain without being able to view your template, but I believe it is a matter of unescaping the html within the template (which can be done by using 3 braces instead of 2).

> All variables are HTML-escaped by default. If you want to render unescaped HTML, >use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}. You can also use & to unescape a variable.

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

(possible duplicate [Text as HTML in Mustache.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834419/text-as-html-in-mustache-js))